# Flask, How can I response the picture on the page

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and web development, I want to upload a picture and process it by my deep learning application and then response the processed picture on the page, here is my frame work code

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import uuid

import PIL.Image as Image
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, send_from_directory


ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(list(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/tmp'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def process_image(file_path):
    """
    resize image to 32x32
    :param file_path: file path
    :return:
    """
    img = Image.open(file_path, mode='r')
    return img.resize([32,32], Image.ANTIALIAS)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    _path = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        _file = request.files['file']
        print(_file)
        if _file and allowed_file(_file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(_file.filename)
            _path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            _file.save(_path)
            return show_pic(deep_learning(_path))

    return '''
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <title>Web App/title>
            <h1>Deep Learning Web App</h1>
            <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
            '''


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

As you can see it, I have implemented upload picture function and the function `deep_learning(path)`, and it return the path of processed picture, I need to implement function `show_pic()`, how can I do that?

Comment: remove the leading `_` from your variable names. What did you think, they are good for? `allowed_file` is simply `return filename.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/) with your html skeleton and pass the image path to the `render_template()` function.

*result.html*

```
<html>
  <img src="{{ image_path }}">
</html>
```

Add this to your view function:

```
return render_template('result.html', image_path=deep_learning(_path))
```

For this to work your files need to be located in the `static`directory or a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can define _file(processed file) with `None` value below form tag check if file not none then show it:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    _path = None 
    _file = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        _file = request.files['file']
        print(_file)
        if _file and allowed_file(_file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(_file.filename)
            _path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            _file.save(_path)

    return '''
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <title>Web App/title>
            <h1>Deep Learning Web App</h1>
            <form ...> 
             ...
            </form>
            {% if _file%}
              <img src="{{url_for('uploaded_file', filename=_file) }}" > 
            {% endif %}
            '''
```